# Bad Path After Uploading File inside Folder in Dropbox

Tags: php, dropbox-api

I have a function that will upload product images to dropbox after an order has been made in my website.

I customize the path name to :

```
$dropBoxRoot = '/Comp#'.$user['company_id'].'/Prop#'.$user['object_id'].'/Order#'.$orderId.'/'.$product;
```

I checked if the said path has existed by using the `getDelta` function.

```
//let's assume $this-client has already instantiated
$checkIfFolderExist = $this->client->getDelta(null, $dropBoxRoot);
```

After that, I uploaded that image by doing this:

```
//the actual path : /Comp#119/Prop#5/Order#120/Product1/image.png
$this->client->uploadFile($dropBoxRoot.'/'.$fileName, WriteMode::add(), $file, $size);
```

The image is uploaded in the dropbox. I can see it there inside the path but after uploading, the `uploadFile` function returns an exception:

```
(1/1) InvalidArgumentException

'path': bad path: must start with "/": "image.png"
 in Path.php (line 141)
```

If anyone has the same situation, I would like to ask your advices. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that it will return the error if the `path` parameter is  concatenated.

In `uploadFile` function, I made it like this:

```
$dropBoxRoot.'/'.$fileName
```

So I make a new variable to concatenate the final path:

```
$finalPath = $dropBoxRoot.'/'.$fileName;

$this->client->uploadFile($finalPath, WriteMode::add(), $file, $size);
```

And so it returns without the exception this time.